# What's the ID of a cookie?

Tags: asp.net, cookies, session-cookies

is it possible to have two cookies with the same

- Name
- Host and
- Path

For example:

**cookie #1**

```
name=.ASPXAUTH
content: D06BB....
Host: www.mydomain.com
Path:/
Expires: 2-12-2015
```

**cookie #2**

```
name=.ASPXAUTH
content: 46458....
Host: www.mydomain.com
Path:/
Expires: 2-12-2016
```

So my question: if is technically possible to have both of these two cookies at the same time?

Comment: have you tried? see what happens. easily tested, and also the best way to learn.

Comment: the issue came up because of a user report - he said he has two cookies with same host/path/name ... but actually that was just wrong, so everything's like it should be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, setting `cookie #2` would overwrite `cookie #1` since they have the same name.

If what you propose was indeed possible, it would be impossible to change the value of an existing cookie, because doing so would create a new cookie.

Multiple cookie name/value pairs **can** exist as long as the path is different (or the domain obviously). You can refer to [RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109.html) for more details.